# Specify default charset using open-uri but use server-provided charset if given

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, open-uri

Using `open()` from Ruby's `open-uri`, I want to fetch files from arbitrary servers not under my control.  Servers may specify a Content-Type for a file, e.g. `text/calendar; charset=utf-8` or `text/calendar; charset=ISO-8859-1`, in which case I am glad that `open()` will believe that the charset is whatever the server claims.  However, if the server does not specify a charset, then `open()` seems to assume the charset is "ASCII-8BIT."  I want to make `open()` instead assume the charset is "UTF-8" *(when no charset is specified)*, since `text/calendar`, i.e. "iCal files," should normally be encoded as "UTF-8."

I put emphasis on only assuming the charset *when no charset is specified*, because I still want to respect servers' decisions to optionally serve files in whatever charset they please.

I tried `open('http://my-test-uri.test', 'r:UTF-8')`, but that unconditionally overrides the charset, even if the server specifies a different charset like "ISO-8859-1."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OpenURI::Meta#charset` accepts a block which will return a charset only if the server did not specify one.

Using that information, we can set the encoding of the `StringIO` returned by `open` to either the same encoding it had (redundantly) or to our default:

```
open('http://localhost:3333').tap do |io|
  charset = io.charset { 'utf-8' }
  io.set_encoding(charset)
end
```